# Riemann Integral Exercise

Tags: real-analysis, integration

1. $Let f:[0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying

$$\int_0^x f(t) dt = \int_x^1 f(t) dt, \qquad \forall x \in[0, 1]. $$

Prove that $f(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in [0, 1]. $

I'm trying to think about the criterion of integrability and use things like the mean value theorem for integrals but don't seem to be getting anywhere does anyone reckon they could help me out or give me a hint?

Comment: You could show $f=-f$...

Answer (score 5):

Differentiating both sides gives 
$$f(x)=-f(x)$$
or $$f(x)=0$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$.